# Data update Codeigniter with session

Tags: codeigniter, session

The problem is that when I click on the save button, the data is listed in the database. In this case, the user's name remains the same in the head, and only when I do logged_in it will change. How can I change the name with the help of a session without going out of the dashboard.

Model:

```
function get_user_by_id($id){
    $user = $this->ci->db
        ->where($this->identifier_field, $id)
        ->get($this->user_table);

    $user_details = $user->row();
    return $user_details;
}

function get_user($data)
{
    $this->ci->db->select('*');
    $this->ci->db->from('users');
    $this->ci->db->where('id', $data);
    $query = $this->ci->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}

// Update Query For Selected Student
    function update_user($id, $data)
    {
        $this->ci->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->ci->db->update('users', $data);
    }
```

Controller:

```
function show_user()
{
    $data = array(
        'lang' => $lang,
        'test_condition' => false,
        'reg_condition' => false,
        'current_page' => '',
        'head_title' => $lang['profile']
    );

    $id = $this->session->userdata('identifier');
    $data['user'] = $this->authentication->get_user_by_id($id);
    /*$data['single_user'] = $this->authentication->get_user($id);*/
    $this->load->view('profile', $data);
}

function profile()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    if (isset ($id)) {
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'birthday' => $this->input->post('birthday'),
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'language_id' => $this->input->post('language'),

        );
        $this->authentication->update_user($id, $data);
    }
    $this->show_user();
}
```

Comment: post the variable you used to print the name., or post your head view block where you print the name

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of this question, this is where your problem lies

```
function profile(){

$id = $this->input->post('id');
if (isset ($id)) {
    $data = array(
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'birthday' => $this->input->post('birthday'),
        'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
        'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
        'language_id' => $this->input->post('language'),

    );
    $this->authentication->update_user($id, $data);
}
$this->show_user();
}
```

Now let me explain why I feel so,

First, in your profile function, you defined $id from your post data, but looking at your show_user method, you defined $id from a session

```
$id = $this->session->userdata('identifier');
```

Next you check if $id is set, now whether or not $id is set, the show_user function is called

```
$this->show_user();
```

Now that implies that, in case $id is not set, then the update process is not performed, yet you still call the show_user function, that is to say the values in the database does not change, yet you call the show_function to display updated details

Solution: First, you should define $id from your session and not from post. then insert the show_user function call inside the if block, so its only called if the update is done, else do something else. So your profile function should be like this

```
function profile(){ 

    $id = $this->session->userdata('identifier');
    if ($id != null) {
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'birthday' => $this->input->post('birthday'),
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'language_id' => $this->input->post('language'),

        );

        $this->authentication->update_user($id, $data);

        redirect(base_url('classname/show_user'));

    }else{
        //do something else
    }

}
```

I hope this helps you out. If you find any difficulty, kindly comment and lets sort it out

Comment: The idea that you gave a very cool, but the following problem: _Error Number: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kyokushinkai_dev`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`gender`) REFERENCES `genders` (`id`))_

Comment: `function profile()
    {
        $id = $this->session->userdata('identifier');
        if ($id != null) {
            $data = array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'birthday' => $this->input->post('birthday'),
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            );
            $this->authentication->update_user($id, $data);
            redirect(base_url('show_user'));
        }else{ $this->show_user();
        }
        $this->show_user();
    }`

Comment: But that was not the problem you outlined. I gave you a solution based on your request

Comment: The problem you are having is not found in your question. I think you have a different problem, maybe you should modify your question to suit the current problem you are having

Answer (score 0):

When you click on save button. Used this:

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

try to get the last inserted id and find that record with the search query like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table_name',array('id'=>last inserted id));
$query = $query->row_array();
```

And after that update the session with the help of this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session name',$query);
```